# How to run storage link command on forge

Tags: laravel, forge

i'm new to laravel. And I have the website up now with forge. The only issue is that I cannot see or store the photos. Do I have to write the storagelink command somewhere, and if then, where exactly? I changed the file system driver to public on the env file as well

Comment: You could SSH on to your server and run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to SSH into server and run it manually from
/home/forge/yoursitename
then
php artisan storage:link

The reason is that usually this will be done in deployment post-composer commands, but when you use the Git Repository method for deployment, the rule of thumb .gitignore setup for Laravel is to ignore the storage directory completely. So you should always go check, odds are in many cases, specially if you haven't edited your .gitignore directly you will be missing the storage folders, make sure the folder exists and all its subdirectories. /app, /cache, framework, and in this case most importantly /public.

Odds are if you are having issues that folder might not exist.

Otherwise other methods suggested here do work too. Not sure why poor Adnane, got a -1 but even that method should work for using a route to call Artisan.

All the storage link method does is check whether the OS is windows or Linux and create a symlink for the folder. I sometimes even change mine as I see fit.

Also the filesystem that you changes to "public" is supposed to be "local", the storage path, and filesystem driver are two separate things.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that by creating the symbolic link using the facade `Artisan`

basically you will need to create a new route at `web.php` as bellow :

```php
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

and , of course , don't forget to import the class at the very top of the file like so :

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

make sure you update the hosted file as changed .

and simply , to create your symlink , you will need to navigate to `/linkstorage` and that's it !